# PrimeNg column filtering

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

Actually, I want to use the column filtering for the field isActive.

Details from api,

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Demo1",
    "isActive": false

  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Demo2",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Demo3",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Demo4",
    "isActive": true
  }
]
```

I want to display the values in table.In the **isActive** field, want to display **active** for **true** and **inactive** for false.

And I used the below code for this

```
  <td class="text-center">
      <span [class]="division.isActive? 'badge badge-success' : 'badge 
     badge-danger'">{{division.isActive == true ? "ACTIVE":INACTIVE" }} 
     </span>
   </td>
```

Below is the sample table

```
id           value         isActive
------------------------------------
1            Demo1          INACTIVE
2            Demo2          ACTIVE
3            Demo3          INACTIVE
4            Demo4          ACTIVE
```

As I want to use active/inactive in the filter to get values. But because of API values (true/false) I can only use true/false.

Below is the interface which I have used.

```
 export class Division {
  constructor(
   public id: string,
   public name: string,
   public isActive: string
  ) { }
 }
```

Can we write the Active/Inactive condition here? Is this possible, can you help me out?

Comment: Can you add the logic in your component.ts file?

Comment: PrimeNG filtering is working by the interface. I want to know, how to write the logic in interface ?? or is there any other way??

Comment: If we write the logic in component.ts, how to write??

Comment: Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult to help you with your exact problem without seeing the logic in your component. I will instead give you an idea of how you I would solve this issue.

- Add an external filter outside the table like an [InputSwitch](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputswitch) (show Deactivated)
- When slider true show all. When slider false show only isActive === true

Comment: Please check this link,  "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8lc7i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct.ts". Actually we used stackblitz to share our logic. But its too not working.. I think you get the logic which we used. We used the API and called in product.service.ts. And interfaces in product.ts. All functions we wrote in component.ts.  Its not working, but I think you will understand what we mean?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Kindly try to help us

Comment: The stackblitz is not working. There is no data displayed in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm third party package for achieve your target

> ng2-smart-table

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table